# How to trigger refresh on a page from another page (no redirect)?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

So, what I have is a lot of pages like this, with GET parameters: `benchmark.php?game_id=87`
that display the information about the particular game (info is in a database) and also contains an Edit button.

The Edit button opens a new window using JS `window.open("edit_game.php?game_id=87",...)`
The Edit window contains a few textboxes to add/modify data and a Save button.

The desired behaviour here is that when I press the Save button on the `edit_game.php` page, not only that the information is saved in the DB (this works) but also the `benchmark.php?game_id=87` page is maybe refreshed so that the information displayed is actual. I don't know how to do the 'submit on page x, page y is aware and refreshes'.

I assume I should use AJAX for this but I don't know where to start. What I tried is something like this

```
setInterval( function(){
        $('#refresh_station').load('game_information.php');
    }, 2000);
```

that every 2 seconds it refreshes the information present in `benchmark.php?game_id=87` but I find this very inefficient since it refreshes the info even if no modifications happened.

Is this the only way to approach this situation?

Edit: I should mention that `edit_game.php?game_id=87` is not supposed to close or anything after pressing Save. So I can't just use the submit form to redirect back to `benchmark.php`.

Comment: You will either have to make the edit form a popup instead of a new window and refresh the page content on Ajax success or Auto refresh the page content every few seconds.

Comment: You really need to use **ajax**

Comment: I don't mind using AJAX, as I said. I would like some pointers into how to aproach this particular situation using it.

Comment: Do not refresh you page every few seconds that is a terrible idea for something like this. If there is just a pop-up you still have access to the DOM of the page update it with the data you sent on successful Ajax

Comment: Oh it is a new window. I would suggest making a modal overlay new windows make something like this very challenging.

Comment: Even if it is very challenging, I'm asking: is it possbile this way? Where to start looking for information to do this?

Comment: Ok, it seems fine. I'll try to debug my code as to see why it doesn't work for me. Thanks

Comment: You're most welcome :)

Comment: Working example now located at: http://www.webl.es/stackoverflow/popuprefresh.php (couldn't use JSfiddle or other comparable websites because they don't work with popups)

Comment: I would highly recommend events. check out the answer. For the same reason @LaurensSwart mentioned, you will need to run the code locally (and change the localserver to match your page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running a loop that checks every few seconds whether the records have changed isn't the best solution in my opinion. There's a much easier way to trigger a page refresh when you submit a form in a popup window.

Using `window.opener` you can perform actions on the window that opened the popup that you're currently in. In your case:

```
<form onsubmit="window.opener.location.reload();">
Your form here.
<input type="submit" value="Save changes">
</form>
```

Or in jQuery:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    window.opener.location.reload();
});
```

Comment: I tried the method (that seems great in theory), but it simply redirects after pressing the Save button

Comment: Hi Florina. What do you mean it redirects? You're opening a popup window right? And this popup window has the edit_game.php page. Once you hit save, you want the original window (the main window) to reload, correct?

Comment: Yes. I want the main window to refresh, but the popup to stay the same. Using this method makes the popup become the main window (ergo redirect)

Comment: @Florina hope Laurens can help if you post the updated code, as I can see his suggest should work.

Comment: Please see a working example with the exact code posted above: http://www.webl.es/stackoverflow/popuprefresh.php (check source of index.php and popup.html) (Sorry, couldn't use jsfiddle or other such site because it doesn't allow for popups)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you should use Ajax for it also add one field in Database table last_update, now when page edit_game.php?game_id=87 load it have last_update time, ajax check this last update on some interval time if ajax see there is any update page should be refreshed.

Comment: I guess this would be the most efficient way. But since I have a lot of users and a lot of games, I might aswell refresh every 2 seconds and end up the same

Comment: If you need Ajax code for it, i have no issue just revert for ajax code @Florina

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/yqv1eh8w/1/

```
postMessage
```

can communicate with the child window. [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)

```
window.addEventListener("message", function (event) {});
```

will let you listen to it from a child window.

This should be help you with what you want. 
The entire thing communicates with the help of events and messages.

Also, you will need to run this locally (coz I opened popups to the same window)

Answer (score -1):

IMO, the best approach is to use a popup form. If your web page is already using Bootstrap, you can add a modal popup easily with the edit form as it's content. When clicking on the edit button, instead of opening a new window, you can open this popup.

Then submit this form with ajax on click of the submit button and inside the Ajax success function, add javascript/jQuery to close the modal and refresh the page content.

Comment: OP gave no indication of using Boostrap.

Comment: That's why I mentioned "If". Otherwise she can use any popup plugin.

Comment: "IMO" and "If" do not make answers they make suggestions which are appropriate for comments not answers